# Select only the first object from sparql query

Tags: rdf, sparql

I would like to get Daft Punk's discography from dbpedia, and for each album I would like to show: 
1) The title
2) The release year
3) The wikipedia page,
so I wrote this query:

```
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT  str(?name) YEAR(?relDate) AS ?relYear ?wiki WHERE {
    ?album a d:Album .
    ?album foaf:name ?name .
    ?album d:artist :Daft_Punk .   
    ?album foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wiki .
    ?album d:releaseDate ?relDate .       
}

ORDER BY ?relDate
```

Which works, except for the fact that there is one album (Alive 2007) which has 2 different release years (as you can see [here](http://dbpedia.org/page/Alive_2007)), but I would like to show only the earliest of the 
two. How should I edit my query to make this album appear only once with the first date? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `MIN` [aggregate](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) to extract the minimum value of the release year, when the result has been grouped using the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby) feature of [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).

For example, something like this:

```
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT str(?name) MIN(YEAR(?relDate)) AS ?relYear ?wiki
WHERE {
    ?album a d:Album .
    ?album foaf:name ?name .
    ?album d:artist :Daft_Punk .   
    ?album foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wiki .
    ?album d:releaseDate ?relDate .       
}
GROUP BY ?name ?wiki
ORDER BY ?relYear
```