# Use second filter when there are multiple entries in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have the following query:

```
PREFIX  owl: <http://carre.kmi.open.ac.uk/ontology/risk.owl#>

SELECT distinct ?name ?value ?condition ?condition_json 
WHERE
{
?node owl:has_observable_condition ?condition .
?node owl:has_risk_evidence_ratio_value ?value .
?node owl:has_risk_factor ?factor.
?factor owl:has_risk_factor_target ?target.
?target owl:has_risk_element_name ?name.
?node owl:has_observable_condition_json ?condition_json .
FILTER regex(str(?condition), "OB_58") .}
```

The results of the query can be found [here](https://devices.duth.carre-project.eu/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fpublic&query=PREFIX%20%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fontology%2Frisk.owl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fname%20%3Fvalue%20%3Fcondition%20%3Fcondition_json%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition%20%3Fcondition%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20owl%3Ahas_risk_evidence_ratio_value%20%3Fvalue%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor%20%3Ffactor.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffactor%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor_target%20%3Ftarget.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftarget%20owl%3Ahas_risk_element_name%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition_json%20%3Fcondition_json%20.FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fcondition%29%2C%20%22OB_58%22%29%20.%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

As you can see in the first column, all entries (is that the correct term?) have 3 element names, which makes the data repeat themselves 2 times. Is there some way to only show one? (preferably the english one?) I tried

```
PREFIX  owl: <http://carre.kmi.open.ac.uk/ontology/risk.owl#>

SELECT distinct ?name ?value ?condition ?condition_json 
WHERE
{
  ?node owl:has_observable_condition ?condition .
  ?node owl:has_risk_evidence_ratio_value ?value .
  ?node owl:has_risk_factor ?factor.
  ?factor owl:has_risk_factor_target ?target.
  ?target owl:has_risk_element_name ?name.
  ?node owl:has_observable_condition_json ?condition_json .
  FILTER (regex(str(?condition), "OB_58")&&regex(str(?name), "en")) .}
```

but it returns an empty table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478234/select-only-the-first-object-from-sparql-query) didn't work (or I couldn't adapt it to my situation).

Comment: `filter(langmatches(lang(?name), 'en'))`

Comment: you are awesome, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "entries" appear to be `risk_factor_target`s (`owl:has_risk_factor_target`), which have multiple values for their `risk_element_name`s (`owl:has_risk_element_name`).

Those `risk_element_name` values appear to be differently lang-tagged translations that are meant to have the same meaning.

@AKSW's suggestion of `filter(langmatches(lang(?name), 'en'))` is good, but note that this will only return `?target`s for which there *is* an English `?name`.

Complete revised [query](https://devices.duth.carre-project.eu/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fpublic&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fontology%2Frisk.owl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fname%20%3Fvalue%20%3Fcondition%20%3Fcondition_json%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcondition%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_evidence_ratio_value%20%20%3Fvalue%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffactor%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffactor%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor_target%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftarget%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftarget%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_element_name%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition_json%20%20%3Fcondition_json%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fcondition%29%2C%20%22OB_58%22%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Fname%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) and [results](https://devices.duth.carre-project.eu/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fpublic&query=PREFIX%20%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcarre.kmi.open.ac.uk%2Fontology%2Frisk.owl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fname%20%3Fvalue%20%3Fcondition%20%3Fcondition_json%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcondition%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_evidence_ratio_value%20%20%3Fvalue%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffactor%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffactor%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_factor_target%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftarget%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftarget%20%20owl%3Ahas_risk_element_name%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fnode%20%20%20%20owl%3Ahas_observable_condition_json%20%20%3Fcondition_json%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fcondition%29%2C%20%22OB_58%22%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Fname%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) --

```
PREFIX  owl: <http://carre.kmi.open.ac.uk/ontology/risk.owl#>

SELECT distinct ?name ?value ?condition ?condition_json 
WHERE
{
  ?node    owl:has_observable_condition       ?condition .
  ?node    owl:has_risk_evidence_ratio_value  ?value .
  ?node    owl:has_risk_factor                ?factor .
  ?factor  owl:has_risk_factor_target         ?target .
  ?target  owl:has_risk_element_name          ?name .
  ?node    owl:has_observable_condition_json  ?condition_json .
  FILTER regex(str(?condition), "OB_58") .
  FILTER (langmatches(lang(?name), 'en')) 
}
```

Comment: thanks, I assume all entries will have at least an English name, and all the entries I need appear in the results. I ended up using FILTER (regex(str(?condition), "OB_58")&&langmatches(lang(?name), 'en')) , I didn't know you can stack filters like that (first time using sparql)