# get relYear or released in dbpedia singles data without record duplication

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

[Here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20ont%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fpage%2C%20%3Fartist%2C%20%3FrelYear%2C%20%3Freleased%2C%20%3FrunTime%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fpage%20dct%3Asubject%20dbc%3ABillboard_Hot_100_number-one_singles%20.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fpage%20prop%3Aartist%20%3Fartist%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fpage%20prop%3Arelyear%20%3FrelYear%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fpage%20prop%3Areleased%20%3Freleased%7D.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fpage%20ont%3Aruntime%20%3FrunTime%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) is the browse output of the following query to try to get singles that are in the billboard top 100:

```
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?page, ?artist, ?relYear, ?released, ?runTime WHERE {
  ?page dct:subject dbc:Billboard_Hot_100_number-one_singles .
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:artist ?artist}.
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:relyear ?relYear}.
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:released ?released}.
  OPTIONAL {?page ont:runtime ?runTime}
}
```

I put relYear and released because some singles have one, some have the other, some have both, some have neither.

If you look at the output, it duplicates rows: one row with relYear, a second row with released.  I want something like SQL `COALESCE(released, relYear)`, i.e. give me the first element of (released, relYear) that exists, on a single row.

How do I do that?

P.S. I have the same problem with artist and musicalArtist, and so on, so the rows end up multiplying like crazy.

P.P.S. Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478234/select-only-the-first-object-from-sparql-query#15481158), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you already know the answer, use [`COALESCE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce):

```
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?page ?artist (coalesce(?relYear, ?released) as ?releaseYear) ?runTime WHERE {
  ?page dct:subject dbc:Billboard_Hot_100_number-one_singles .
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:artist ?artist}.
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:relyear ?relYear}.
  OPTIONAL {?page prop:released ?released}.
  OPTIONAL {?page ont:runtime ?runTime}
}
```

But, and I guess you already figured out, that there can be multiple versions of the same single, done by different artists and done in different versions, thus, you might get multiple rows for the same single. As an extreme example, have a look at `Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart`

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+
|             page             |             artist             | releaseYear | runTime |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        1983 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        1983 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        1995 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        1995 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        2012 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        2012 |   180.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        1983 |   230.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        1983 |   230.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        1995 |   230.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        1995 |   230.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Bonnie Tyler"^^rdf:langString |        2012 |   230.0 |
| :Total_Eclipse_of_the_Heart  | "Nicki French"^^rdf:langString |        2012 |   230.0 |
| ...                          | ...                            |         ... |     ... |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------+---------+
```

You could do some kin of [`group by`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) here, to get at least for each artist only one row, e.g. in combination with [`group_concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rAggregate) or [`sample`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rAggregate)

Comment: I accepted your answer, thanks! But .. what is group_concat? I searched, and it's hard to get a straight answer.